# How do I use <VirtualHost> in httpd.conf Amazon linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache2, httpd.conf

I have tried all the possible solution to point mydomain.com to a specific folder under `/var/www/html/mysite`. First of all `httpd.conf` file is missing under `/etc/httpd` but it is found under `/etc/httpd/conf`. Also there is no `/etc/apache2` folder.

To point my domain to `/var/www/html/mysite` I wrote the below code under  `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` just below the line which says `ServerAdmin root@localhost`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/
</VirtualHost>
```

It did work but everything, even the IP is pointing to `/var/www/html/mysite/` .
I am not able to figure out where I am wrong. I just need mydomain.com to point to mysite directory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#defaultvhost):

> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then **the first listed virtual host** that matches that will be used.

Your virtual host of `*:80` accepts all IPs on port 80, so it fits the "first listed virtual host that matches", and that's why it's getting served.

So if you don't like `mydomain.com` being the default virtual host, make another one above it (with no `ServerName`) that just points to a default location.

(BTW, you have `/etc/httpd` instead of `/etc/apache2` because different distributions do things differently. Typically, `httpd` is on CentOS-based servers, `apache2` on Debian family. Configuration layout is also fairly different. This is normal and nothing to worry about.)

Comment: I did try to remove the trailing slash from the DocumentRoot and removed the ServerName but it didn't workout

Comment: I didn't say anything about trailing slash in `DocumentRoot` (even though it is a good advice); why did you comment about it to me? If it works for all hosts with the trailing slash but you only want one hostname to work, the slash makes no difference. Did you try the rest of the things I wrote about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've actually set `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` as appropriate for your installation? Ie with real domains that they are serving...

I think you may need to remove the `/` at the end of `/var/www/html/mysite/`

Also, you may wish to have a read here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html - it explains how the documents are mapped under your documentRoot directory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user that Apache is running from has access to read those files (if you can chmod in AWS, not sure). Also **remove any trailing slashes** from the DocumentRoot.

Provide ErrorLog path (e.g. `ErrorLog /var/log/vhosts/error.log` ) for in-depth debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can check few things:

```
    - Please confirm you have pointed correct ip in A record under DNS management on domain registrar.

    - Are you trying to access site on www version or non-www version. If you are trying to access on www, probably it may not work as I cannot see any ServerAlias in your vhost block.Make sure to restart your apache after making change in vhost for ServerAlias.

- Remove forward slash at end of DocumentRoot line - it should read as /var/www/html/mysite

    - If possible place and entry for 127.0.0.1 mydomain.com in your /etc/hosts file.
```

Answer (score -1):

What error are you getting when your are browsing your domain mydomain.com?

Please make sure to **open the port 80 for incoming traffic at that EC2**, otherwise all the traffic will be refused by default

Comment: The question is about VirtualHosts, not about opening ports in EC2 or security groups